# Javascript change a table cell, from the end of one row, into a table row on it's own - is this possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Id like to change the layout of a table that I'm getting from a SharePoint site.  It's not possible to change the table at the source, but I can add javascript to the page and hopefully modify it.

The problem is that the table is fixed width, and the columns are divided equally, however the last column contains a lot of text, an it makes it difficult to read when it's all squashed up into a narrow column.

What I'd like is to change this (the actual table may have more rows)

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |eeeee|
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |eeeee|
|     |     |     |     |eeeee|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |55555|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |55555|
|     |     |     |     |55555|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

To this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    eeeeeeeeeeeeeee    |
+-----------------------+
|     |     |     |     |
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    555555555555555    |
+-----------------------+
```

I've tried adding extra tags using innerHTML,append/prepend but these only seem to create rows inside the last cell (it could be that I'm doing it wrong?)

Is this even possible? or will it be a case hiding the existing table, and recreating a new one ?
Can anyone provide pointers to the solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your actual HTML code, and the attempt you have made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the exact HTML structure, this is quite easily doable.

**HTML**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table tr").each(function () {
        var cell = $(this).find("td:last-of-type");
        $(this).after("<tr><td colspan='3'>" + cell.html() + "</td></tr>");
        cell.remove();
    });
});
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q7RCq/2/)** for an example.

Comment: You must also remove the last cell (`val`) after copying it in the next row

Comment: `colspan='4'` is an attribute of `<td>` not of `<tr>` ... not use a variable if isn't needed. `$(this).after("<tr colspan='4'><td>" + $(this).find("td:last-of-type").html() + "</td></tr>");` ... :)

Comment: Good points. Updated the answer to reflect changes to remove the last cell and set the `colspan` attribute to the `td`.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's much more than I expected !!

Answer (score 0):

The [following](http://jsfiddle.net/RRtRr/2/) should do it:

```
var numColumns = $('table#foo tr:first td').length - 1;
$('table#foo tr').each(function() {
    $('<tr/>').append($('td:last', this).attr('colspan', numColumns)).insertAfter(this);
});
```